# Print count of xml tag occurrences with particular file name in java

Tags: java, xml

I wrote java code to count xml tag occurrence, retrieving files and file names from directory and sub directories. Can any one help me to get logic to print count of xml tag occurrences with particular file name.
Below are my code snippets.

```
public void parseXml(List<File> xmlFiles, String tagName, List<String> names) {

        for (File xmlFile : xmlFiles) {
            dbFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                docBuild = dbFact.newDocumentBuilder();
                dom = docBuild.parse(xmlFile);
                nl = dom.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
                System.out.println("Total " + tagName + " tags: " + nl.getLength());
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException pe) {
                System.out.println(pe);
            } catch (SAXException se) {
                System.out.println(se);
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                System.out.println(ie);
            }
        }

public static List<File> getFiles(String path){
        File folder = new File(path);
        List<File> resultFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for(File file: listOfFiles){
            if(file.isFile() && file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xml") && !file.getAbsolutePath().contains("settings_")){
                resultFiles.add(file);
            }else if(file.isDirectory()){
                resultFiles.addAll(getFiles(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }

        return resultFiles;
    }

public static List<String> readXmlName(String path){
        File folder = new File(path);
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for(File file: listOfFiles){
            if(file.isFile() && file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xml") && !file.getAbsolutePath().contains("settings_")){
                names.add(file.getName());
            }else if(file.isDirectory()){
                names.addAll(readXmlName(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }

        return names;
    }
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with the code you posted. What do you expect it to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: No problem in posted codes. I want to print count of tag occurrence with particular file name.

Comment: Ex: Total item tags in <filename1.xml>: 10, Total item tags <filename2.xml>: 20, Total item tags in <filename3.xml>: 10 and so on

Comment: If there's no problem, what is your question? If you want the file name in the message, then just add it to the message: `System.out.println("Total " + tagName + " tags in " + xmlFile.getName() + ": " + nl.getLength());`

Comment: Yes. This was my expectation. Thank you.